# Segmented WebVTT not working with Chromecast

Tags: ios, chromecast, webvtt

I am trying to provide closed caption support with Chromecast for my iOS app. The files are in segmented WebVTT format(with .m3u8 extension). But the videos are hosted in a CDN and closed caption files hosted on a separate server. The URLs for these WebVTT files are provided separately and not part of video master playlist. These subtitles are working with native iOS player but not with Chromecast.

I tried hosting a normal WebVTT (non-segmented) file on the same server where segmented WebVTT file is hosted and it works fine. So, the problem is with the segmented WebVTT.

So, is it possible to get the segmented WebVTT files working with Chromecast if they are hosted separately. I am using a Custom receiver. Do I need to add anything to receiver file specifically to support this?

This is how I create the media track for closed caption :

```
GCKMediaTrack *track = [[GCKMediaTrack alloc] initWithIdentifier:1
                                           contentIdentifier:@"https://domain_name/track_name.m3u8"
                                                 contentType:@"text/webvtt"
                                                        type:GCKMediaTrackTypeText
                                                 textSubtype:GCKMediaTextTrackSubtypeCaptions
                                                        name:@"English"
                                                languageCode:@"en-US"
                                                  customData:nil];
```

If we pass an individual segment like this it works properly.

```
GCKMediaTrack *track = [[GCKMediaTrack alloc] initWithIdentifier:1
                                           contentIdentifier:@"https://domain_name/segments/track_index.webvtt"
                                                 contentType:@"text/webvtt"
                                                        type:GCKMediaTrackTypeText
                                                 textSubtype:GCKMediaTextTrackSubtypeCaptions
                                                        name:@"English"
                                                languageCode:@"en-US"
                                                  customData:nil];
```

Comment: Is CORS setup correctly for the server that hosts the VTT segments?

Comment: I have updated the question. The receiver app and the caption files are hosted on the same domain, so I guess CORS support is not needed. Also verified that individual caption segments works properly.

Comment: Could you please open a ticket at https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/list and include the info (and would be great if you could also include a stream)?

Comment: Issue has been posted. Here is the link https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=422&thanks=422&ts=1415193523.

Answer (score 0):

I experience exactly the same thing today, close to five years after this question was posted.

The following subtitle playlist:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:7310
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:7309.400000,
https://undertekst.nrk.no/prod/MSUB19/12/MSUB19121216AW/MIX/MSUB19121216AW-v2.vtt
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:5891.920000,
https://undertekst.nrk.no/prod/MSUB19/12/MSUB19121216BW/TTV/MSUB19121216BW-v2.vtt
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

makes a chromecast display the two segments on top of each other. On iOS devices though, they are offset with the expected 7309.4 seconds, and displays after one another.

Comment: Is this an answer to the question or are you posting because you have the same issue?

Comment: Hello, I do have the same issue. We've stopped publishing HLS including subtitles to chromecast, since this does not work, but the best would certainly have been if chromecast did support subtitles parted in multiple segments, according to specification.

Comment: had the same issue. just a week ago, google pinged me regarding a bug I reported on this. (Have written a workaround, so have not had time to get back and verify if it is still a chromecast issue). ref: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140680612